# DataGridView not sortable when AutoGenerateColumns = true + Anonymous Types?

Tags: linq, sorting, datagridview, jquery-ui-sortable, anonymous-types

Can DataGridView be sortable when is bound to an anonymous type? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this on sort event or wherever else you want the sorting to happen - the thing is you'd have to reload your data:

```
   var query = from c in linq
        select new
        {
            Id = c.Id,
            Data= c.Data,
        } 
        into anonymous
        order by anonymous.Id ascending 
        select anonymous;

     this.yourDataGrid.DataSource = query.AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: How can I check which column header was clicked?